# How can I process task results in Celery?

Tags: python, celery

I have an XMPP chat bot which receives commands and replies to them. I have a task queue using Celery to process the commands, and I want the bot to reply when the commands return. However, I can't find a good way to execute a function whenever each task completes.

For example, something like this would be nice:

```
for result in queue.get_result():
    send_message(result)
```

However, I can't find any info on how to do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://ask.github.com/celery/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.ResultSet

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. iterate() doesn't block forever, but I can hack around that using the intervals. However, removing results just produces a KeyError. Results are a two-string tuple, by the way.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it should block for ever, I'd have thought you'd want to use something like that in the run loop of your chat bot.

Comment: The run loop runs in a separate thread, so I can run something in the main thread. Plus, the run loop is in a separate library, so I don't think I can touch it... The KeyError problem remains, though.

Answer (score 0):

Each task should be responsible for getting back to user.

Comment: That's not possible, unfortunately, I can't marshal the class that's responsible for sending the messages...